# Ubuntu reinstallation side by side with Windows XP

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

Here's the issue: my partition table is a mess:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   126435960    63217949    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       302230845   312480314     5124735   1c  Hidden W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda3       312480315   312576704       48195   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda4       126437374   302230844    87896735+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       173694844   237970844    32138000+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       237970908   302230844    32129968+  83  Linux
/dev/sda7       126437376   171616255    22589440   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       171618304   173692927     1037312   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I want to leave the Windows XP on my computer only. Remove the GRUB. Remove all the Linux editions. And reinstall Ubuntu only upgrade it to the newer version.

Any advice on how to do that? Many thanks in advance :)

btw. I also had the Win8.1 installed before.
1. I have removed it by formatting D drive from XP and then 
2. reinstalled GRUB.

Is this a good idea to go into the XP and format all the partitions except those with XP? Will that be enough? What bout the boot loader? I don't have a bootable CD with Windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not select the "reinstall" option, that will wipe out the disk.  Select "Something Else", then since you know what partitions you are using, use those for the installation, and checkoff the format box.  This is pretty straightforward, after you dodge the "reinstall" wording  issue.